# I want to align the starting place of two texts

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I have one "row" and two "text" widgets inside. I want to align the starting place of two texts. ie "m. name" and "m105" should line up.

[image]

```
Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          "M. Adı: ",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(
                    //   width: 20,
                    // ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        "$productName",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 3,
                        softWrap: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,` to your Row widget it should be aligned as you desired or still if it doesnt works just try changing center with other values check which one works for you...

and even after adding above property to your Row widget then you would have to remove **alignment of topleft** in your text of `m.name`

Answer (score 0):

Try

Row() widget attribute

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

Text() widget attribute

```
textAlign: TextAlign.start,
```

Answer (score 0):

/// Try something like that

```
 Row(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: <Widget>[
          Text(
              "M. Adı: ",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 5),
          Flexible(
              child: Text( 
                        "$productName",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,    
                    ),
         ),
     ],
 ),
```